# Как правильно перенести проект ASP.Net MVC на другой сервер? Ошибка 0x80070021 HTTP Error 500.19. НЕ ДУБЛИКАТ! Решения проблемы нет на др сайтах

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Я скомпилировал проект и хочу перенести его на другой сервер. 
Скопировав файлы, при попытке запустить множество ошибок. Гугл и ютуб не помог.
Что можно сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @PashaPash это не дубликат. На той странице нет решения проблемы

Comment: это полный дубликат - тот же код, та же ошибка - даже на той же строчке. Решается точно так же - установкой роли или фичи Application Development. Ваш случай отличается - т.е. роль установлена, но ошибка та же? Тогда об этом стоит явно написать в вопросе, желательно приложив вывод `powershell Get-WindowsFeature`

Comment: решилось установкой всего комплекта компонентов в “установке и удалении программ-＞ IIS”

Comment: осторожно, некоторые вещи из комплекта неожиданно влияют на работу MVС. Например, WebDAV отломает вам MVC WebAPI :(

Comment: @PashaPash кстати хотел как-то поднять WebDav Server (ооочень хотелось) на Windows 10- нифига не вышло....а всё как по инструкции делал.